# CORS Request Failing only on Firefox

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, firefox, cors, webgl

I'm working with Unity WebGL and i'm having an issue with CORS when the loader tries to download the needed unityweb files for the build.

**The error:**

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at "file link". (Reason: CORS request was not successful). State code: (null).

**The code:**

```
if (window.msJsonUrl && typeof window.createUnityInstance !== 'undefined' && !AppManager.gameInstace)
        {
            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", window.msJsonUrl, false);
            request.send(null)
            var data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
            var buildUrl = window.msJsonUrl.substring(0, window.msJsonUrl.lastIndexOf("/")) + "/";
            var config = {
                dataUrl: buildUrl + data.dataUrl,
                frameworkUrl: buildUrl + data.wasmFrameworkUrl,
                codeUrl: buildUrl + data.wasmCodeUrl
            };
            AppManager.gameInstace = window.createUnityInstance(document.getElementById(AppManager.VIEWER_ID), config, this.onProgress.bind(this)
            ).then((unityInstance) => {
                AppManager.gameInstace = unityInstance
                this.canvas = AppManager.gameInstace.Module.canvas
                this.onProgress(1)
             }).catch((message) => {
                alert(message);
            });
            this.setState({objectIsLoading: false, rendererIsLoading: true})
        }
```

Works on every other browser except on firefox.

Any idea why?

Comment: why react tag??

Comment: usually CORS errors occur when tryng to access local resources from the browser. That can be easily solved with vs code's [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) extension

Comment: @rustyBucketBay because the code is writen in a react component... i will look into that extension

Comment: oh, so the unity built html can be copy/pasted in a react component directly and that works?¿

Comment: @rustyBucketBay not really like that.. basically you can create a react component and place the unity instance inside to render it as a component, through the code you see above

`AppManager.gameInstace = window.createUnityInstance(document.getElementById(AppManager.VIEWER_ID), config, this.onProgress.bind(this)...)`

I'm getting the Viewer component and assigning to the rendering of the unity build.